# Converting edit text to html android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have used below method to convrt edit text to html.

> String msgtext=Html.toHtml(txtMsg.getText());

But it contains excess attributes like dir.i don't want this excess attribute.How to remove this.

```
<p dir=ltr>Hello</p>
```

Comment: What do you want then?

Comment: you need to parse the html tag using jsoup and then get the value

Comment: @Pankaj I need simply <p>Hello</p>

Comment: @user Check out my answer to decode the value from html.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below :

To decode Html String you can use `Html.fromHtml()`

like

```
Html.fromHtml(txtMsg.getText().toString());
```